# How to split  E-mail address from a text?

Tags: c#

In a text box, I keep E-mail addresses.
for example

```
Text_box.value="a@hotmail.com,b@hotmail.com,c@hotmail.com"
```

How can I split all of the email addresses? Should I use Regex?

Finally, I want to keep any E-mail address which is correctly coded by user

Comment: split is enough for this

Comment: @Andrew Collins - and now you have 2 problems...

Comment: Everyone is giving the same explanation but they are all forgetting you are probably adding a .trim() for each entry :)

Comment: @Zeus - No but only one. Easy one to be edited in future coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only print the matched email address and not which does not match.

```
private void Match()
{
        Regex validationExpression = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");  
        string text = "whatever@gmail;a@hotmail.com,gmail@sync,b@hotmail.com,c@hotmail.com,what,dhinesh@c";  
        MatchCollection matchCollection = validationExpression.Matches(text);  
        foreach (var matchedEmailAddress in matchCollection)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(matchedEmailAddress.ToString());  
        }  
        Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

This will print

a@hotmail.com
b@hotmail.com
c@hotmail.com

Other things will not be matched by regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] s=Text_box.Text.split(',');
Regex R=new Regex("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b");
var temp=from t in s  where R.IsMatch(t) select t;
List<string> final=new List<string>();
final.addrange(temp);
```

use this

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] emails = list.Split(new char[]{','});
```

Comment: If you check the Split() method you'll notice the "params" keyword on the char[] parameter. This allows you to go like:

list.Split(','); OR list.Split(',', '|'); etc

Answer (score 0):

```
"a@hotmail.com,b@hotmail.com,c@hotmail.com".Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to split string.

1) Every string type object has method called **Split()** which takes array of characters or array of strings. Elements of this array are used to split given string.

```
 string[] parts  = Text_box.value.Split(new char[] {','});
```

2) Although string.Split() is enough in this example, we can achieve same result using regular expressions. Regex to split is :

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(Text_box.value,@",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct regexp to find all forms of email adresses (with latin letters).
Check on wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address ) for correct syntax of email address (easier way) or in RFC5322, 5321 (much harder to understand).

I'm using this:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|""(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*"")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```